# iText use measurement pixel from HTML

Tags: itext, measurement

I generate my PDF pages from HTML.
Is there any possibility for a measurement?

I use width and height from HTML which is px (Pixel).
Is there any dependencies for px and centimeter?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If there's any one who understands this question, I'd appreciate some clarification. In PDF, you define a page size, e.g. A4, Letter,... The measurement unit is the user unit which by default corresponds with the typographical point: 1 inch = 72 points. It is unclear why @internet talks about centimeters. The sentence *Is there any possibility for a measurement?* doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, I will explain again :) Currently I use HMTL for creating my PDF File. In this HTML I use some <div style="width: 100px; margin-top:100px; margin-left: 300px; height: 240px;"> The measurements are in there px. I save all this <div> in my database. Afterwards I want to crearte my PDF with the saved measures (height, width...). My problem is now a relation from 1nch?? to pixel. Do you know what I mean?